# Loading screen until Background Img of Component is loaded. React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to show a loading screen until a component within a main parent component loads its background image. Most of the articles I found were dealing with images placed directly into the DOM as  tags. I have a component that uses a background image.

Here is my Home component which acts as my main container for all components:

```
class Home extends React.Component {

constructor() {
    super();
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <Helmet>
                <link id="favicon" rel="icon" href="../SB.png" type="image/x-icon"/>
                <title>Snow Bounds</title>
            </Helmet>
            <CustomNavBar />
            <HeroUnit />
            <RoadMap />
            <TeamFAQ />
            <Footer />
        </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Home;
```

The component in question is the HeroUnit Component which is as follows:

```
    class HeroUnit extends React.Component {

   
    render()
    {   
        return (
            <div id="home" className={`fullHeightContainer m-auto bg-primary-hero grad bg-info py-4`} style={{position: "relative"}}>
                <Snowfall snowflakeCount={50} color={"rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)"} />
                <Container className="h-100">
                    <div className="heroMainBG h-100" style={{position: "relative",zIndex: 1000}}>
                        
                    </div>
                </Container>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default HeroUnit;
```

How can I make a loading screen show up until the Hero Unit heroMainBg is loaded?

Let me know if you need any other code.. :)

Comment: You can create a `new Image()` and set its `.src`. The browser will then load the image. Add an `onload` event listener to it and then set it as the background-image inside (by using a state). You should have all the pieces you need, you just need to put them together. (Also no, I'm not going to post a code example)

Comment: Is there not a simpler way to do this? I just want to display a loading screen for a DOM element to be loaded really

Comment: When you use a URL as background image the browser creates an Image object and starts loading the image from the server in the background. When it is done, it fires a "load" event. The only other way to display a "loading screen" would be to also add a `background-color` to the element; this will show the color while the image is loading. Also, please don't ask people if there's a simpler way. There isn't. Not here, and not elsewhere.

Comment: Try to use functional components, especially for those that don't really use any internal logic. You don't need to write a class for those. Next, google "react image hook" and you will find a bunch of examples and libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this

```
class Home extends React.Component {

constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      loaded: false;
     }
}

render() {
window.addEventListener("load", event => {
    var image = document.querySelector('add the id or className');
    var isLoaded = image.complete && image.naturalHeight !== 0;
    if(isLoaded)this.setState({loaded:true});
    alert(isLoaded);   // this tells you whether the image has loaded or not 
});
    return (
        this.state.loaded&&<div>
            <Helmet>
                <link id="favicon" rel="icon" href="../SB.png" type="image/x-icon"/>
                <title>Snow Bounds</title>
            </Helmet>
            <CustomNavBar />
            <HeroUnit />
            <RoadMap />
            <TeamFAQ />
            <Footer />
        </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Home;
```

You can add a loader when the image is not loaded :
something like this :

```
!this.state.loaded?<Loader />:Your whole component
```

Comment: Definitely don't use this.

Comment: Why ? what's the issue with this ?

Comment: For one, you're adding a "load" event listener to window, not the image. This code is therefore not reusable at all. Next, this is a React question. You're adding the bad event listener inside the render() method, which means it will get added over and over again. You need to post a robust solution useful for future readers, and one that uses React as the mechanism.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback . Will definitely try improving it .

Comment: Should I delete the answer ?

Comment: Yes, the basic approach won't work even if you fix it.

Comment: Can you write the correct code ?

Comment: So , that I also can learn from this !